# checking an element of List is equal an input

Tags: c#

```
namespace OpenXMLSample
{
    public class Datause
    {
        List<Wsdata> data = new List<Wsdata>();

        public IReadOnlyCollection<Wsdata> Readonlydata
        {
            get
            {
                return data.AsReadOnly();
            }
        }


        public void Dataoutput(DateTime dateinput,int x)
        {//mainde x e input gircen unutma 


            while (true)
            {
                x = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("please select:\ninput a date:1 \nclose:2");
                x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (x == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a date in dd/mm/yyyy format:");
                    DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out dateinput);

                    //date ve Dates farki bak
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (data[i].Dates.Equals(dateinput))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Date:", data[i].Dates);
                            Console.WriteLine("Dolar:", data[i].Dolar);
                            Console.WriteLine("Euro:", data[i].Euro);
                        }
                    }

                    //devam falan bak 
                    continue;
                }
                else if (x == 2)
                    break;
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR!, please wtrite 1 or 2");
                    break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `if(data[i].Dates.Equals(dateinput))` block does not run. Also it does not execute the `i++` part of the `for` - loop.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Hi Mustafa, question is not very clear. Can explain what you are looking for?

Comment: Your code has a some issues. At first can you show us where fill your `data` object. At the current state of your code the `data` object is empty and Count will be 0. So the for loop will not be executed. The next point is that the last `else` block is not covered in braces to the `break;` will not belong to the else and therefore it will always break the `while` after the first iteration.

Comment: @MartinBackasch you right my count is 0 but i dont understand why i read the data in another class. but after the i wrote that class the code begun not runing the other class, Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: You only create a new collection, but did not set any values to it. You only return a readonly collection. so you cannot add any values to it.

Comment: @MartinBackasch i need to use the other list but i need to first set values to it.

Comment: You can add a constructor to your class `Datause`, which takes the list of your data as a parameter. And within the constructor, you have to set them to your `data` collection. so you can then iterate over the list in your output method.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime object is a combined object of date and time. it seems like you are ignoring the timepart here. If your `data[i].Dates` is a `DateTime` object too, you can write `if(data[i].Dates.Date.Equals(dateinput.Date))`

However make sure `data[i].Dates` is not a list/array of dates as the name indicates. If so you need to nest another loop.